# Janus GridEx: Add custom row and select a specific row

Tags: row, janus, gridex

I have GridEx object on my form and...

1. I want to add some items in it with a for...next loop. Actually I couldn't find any method for adding a new row with a custom data.
2. I want to select a specific row in that GridEx object. For example: I want to select the 6th row, is there anything like mygrid.rows(6).value or something like that?!

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a GridEX control called `grid`...

To add new data:

```
GridEXRow row = grid.AddItem();
row.BeginEdit();
row.Cells[0].Value = "Whatever"; // refer to columns by index or name
...
row.EndEdit();
```

To retrieve a specific row:

```
GridEXRow row = grid.GetRow(5); // returns the 6th row
```

To select a specific row:

```
grid.MoveTo(5); // moves the selection to the 6th row
```

Answer (score 2):

To add new row to gridex called MyGridEX:

```
object[] data = { "value0", "value1", "value2", ... };
this.MyGridEX.AddItem(data);
```

To select a specific row:

```
this.MyGridEX.GetRow(1); // select the second row
```